# NestJS factory pattern for use service

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, factory, nest

I have 2 types of login. I need to pass the param in the request and use this param in auth service to choose what service for login I should use.
Does mb exist better way?

Body in POST request.

```
{
    "type": "Customer",
    "store": "store24",
    "email": "test333333@email.com",
    "password": "testpass2"
}
```

`authFactory.ts`

```
const loginFactoryTypes = {
  [LOGIN_TYPE.Customer]: CustomerAuthService,
  [LOGIN_TYPE.User]: UserAuthService,
};

export const createLoginFactory = (type: string) => {
  return loginFactoryTypes[type];
};
```

`auth.controller.ts`

```
@Post('/signin')
signInFactory(@Body() signInDto: SignInUserDto & SignInCustomerDto): Promise<unknown> {
  const { type } = signInDto;

  const loginFactory: AuthInterface = createLoginFactory(type);

  return loginFactory.signin(signInDto);
}
```

If I pass param type - Customer then I get this service `CustomerAuthService`.

```
async signin(signInDto: SignInCustomerDto) {
  const customer = await this.customersService.findCustomerByEmail(signInDto);

  const token = this.jwtService.sign({
    id: customer.id,
    email: customer.email,
  });

  return { token, customer };
}
```

But the controller gets me an error on the string.
`loginFactory.signin(signInDto);`

I get the error `loginFactory.signin is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you have this:

```
const loginFactoryTypes = {
  [LOGIN_TYPE.Customer]: CustomerAuthService,
  [LOGIN_TYPE.User]: UserAuthService,
};
```

`loginFactoryTypes[type]` will return a class, not an instance like you've expected.

At the consumer side of `createLoginFactory`, you could leverage on [`moduleRef`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref) to retrieve an instance of that class using Nest's DI system.